# Equivalent circuit problem

Tags: homework

I need to find the values E1,E2,R1,R2,R3 such that circuit (b) becomes equivalent to circuit (a) according to nodes a,b,c.

Using the superposition theorem I found that the potential difference between the nodes a and b is 5V. Thus, E1=95V and E2=90V.

What should I do to find the resistor values?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the 2 circuits are equivalent, you should have the same resistance between any 2 selected terminals. For eg., the resistance between terminals a & b in both circuits should be the same. Likewise resistance between b & c and between a & c.
You will thus get 3 simultaneous equations (one for each pair of terminals) and there are 3 unknowns (R1, R2, R3) so, you can solve this.

While calculating resistance between 2 terminals, you can replace the voltage sources in the circuit with a short.

I am just giving you an idea as this is your homework. Not solving it fully.